# fp-ts: How to flatten one layer of an array of ReaderTaskEither?

Tags: fp-ts

I have the function `getApps` below

```js
import * as RTE from 'fp-ts/es6/ReaderTaskEither';

type ContextResult<A> = RTE.ReaderTaskEither<LoggingContext, Error, A>;

const getApps: ContextResult<Apps[]>[] = marketplaceIds.map(
  marketplaceId => getAppsFromUser(userId, marketplaceId),
);
```

I'm trying to flatten `ContextResult<OwnedApp[]>[]` to `ContextResult<OwnedApp[]>`. How to do it? I tried `flat`, `flatMap` and `sequence` but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

First,  you need `sequenceArray` to turn `ContextResult<Apps[]>[]` into `ContextResult<Apps[][]>`.
When you. have `F<T>[]` and want to turn it into `F<T[]>`, `sequenceArray` is your friend.

Next, from `ContextResult<Apps[][]>` to `ContextResult<Apps[]>`, we can see that we change the type inside `<>` so we will use `map` here. The function passed in to `map` need to be in the shape of `Apps[][] => Apps[]`, and that is `Array.flatten`

```js
import * as RTE from 'fp-ts/es6/ReaderTaskEither';
import * as A from 'fp-ts/es6/ReadonlyArray';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/es6/function';

const flatted: ContextResult<readonly Apps[]> = pipe(
  getApps,
  RTE.sequenceArray,
  RTE.map(A.flatten)
);
```